# Where to integrate AWS Lambda Code in an Angular Application?

Tags: jquery, angular, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an angular application that I have in an s3 bucket. It is running great routing works, etc. What I want to do is incorporate angular forms into my application and use AWS Lambda on the backend. My question is I know how to pass information from a basic front end form using AWS Lambda here is my example using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact-form-button').on('click', function(e){
        AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials('XXXXXXXXXXXX', '0000000000000');
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: 'us-east-1', apiVersion: '2015-03-31'});

        var pullParams = {
            FunctionName: 'marketing-web-dev-createFeedback',
            InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
            LogType: 'Tail',
            Payload: JSON.stringify({
                "feedback_id": makeid(),
                "name": $('#name').val(),
                "email": $('#email').val(),
                "subject": $('#subject').val(),
                "message": $('#message').val()
            })
        };

        lambda.invoke(pullParams, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                prompt(error);
            } else {
                pullResults = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
            }
        });
        var pullResults;
        return false;
    });
});
function makeid(){
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
```

How would I be able to do the same thing with an angular component? Here is the stub of a basic component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,  FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { Customer } from './customer';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-signup',
    templateUrl: './app/customers/customer.component.html'
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    customerForm: FormGroup;
    customer: Customer= new Customer();

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
            feedback_id: '',
            name: '',
            email: '',
            subject: '',
            message: ''
        });

    }

    save() {
        console.log(this.customerForm);
        console.log('Saved: ' + JSON.stringify(this.customerForm.value));
    }
 }
```

I am just not making the connection on how to integrate `AWS Lambda and Angular`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jquery example works, then you should be able to use the same code in Angular. Move the Lambda invocation code inside your Angular components save method and insert the stringified customerform value into the Lambda request payload (instead of your jquery field extracts). Remember to declare AWS : any so that Typescript doesn't fail on compiling your AWS invocations.

That said, a cleaner approach would be that you also use AWS API Gateway to create a HTTP POST API for your Lambda invocation. Then from Angular you would just use http.post.